# RFID reader code to identify more than one tag

Tags: arduino-leonardo

I'm new to using Arduino and I have managed a few changes to this sketch. But I want to check for a second tag if the first one is not correct. I just can't seem to get it to work. I think it would be good if the tag is not a match to ask it to check the next tag and carry on, but I'm not sure how to make this happen.

```
//RFID Password Typer
//If a matching tag is found, the keyboard types
//CTRL-ALT-DEL, then types the password and presses enter
//Which should log you on to a Windows computer
//Or Lock the computer if you're already logged in

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include "Keyboard.h"
#include <Mouse.h>

#define RST_PIN 9         
#define SS_PIN 10        

byte tag[10]={0x64,0xAE,0xDD,0xFC,};
char pswd[]="********\n";      //password, end with just \n
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);  // Create MFRC522 instance

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();              //start SPI
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();       //start RC522 module
  Keyboard.begin();         //start USB keyboard
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);     //LED off
}

void loop() {
  if (!mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()){ return; }
  if (!mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()){ return; }
  for(byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
    if(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i]!=tag[i]){ return; }
  }
  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA(); //stop tag so we don't get repeats
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH); //LED on so we know we've got tag match
  Mouse.click();
  delay(1000);
  Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_CTRL);
  delay(1000);
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
  Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_CTRL);
  Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_ALT);
  Keyboard.press(KEY_DELETE);
  delay(100);
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
  delay(300);
  Keyboard.print(pswd);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW); //LED off
}
```

Comment: Please **edit** your post and format the code using the code formatting markdown (four leading spaces). For help see [Markdown help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help). You should be able to do this by selecting the code and pressing `Ctrl+K` to have your browser do this for you.

Comment: What have tried? You are looping through the UID of the card and exit if one of the bytes are not values. (This is by the way a timing side-channel.). You can just add a second for loop to see if it's equal to another constant tag value. For that you should put the "compare two byte arrays of a given size" logic in a function for easy re-use.

Answer (score 1):

here's how I'd do it ... allowing for 4, 7 and 10 byte uid's (which are all possible apparently)

```
struct tagInfo {
  byte len;
  byte uid[10];
};
struct tagInfo tag[] = { // add your tags here
  // the len is 1, 2 or 3, for lengths 4, 7, and 10
  // you could just use 4, 7, 10 here and not bother
  // with the len * 3 + 1 calculation later
  // the choice is yours, really
  {1, {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04}},
  {1, {0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05}},
  {2, {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07}},
  {1, {0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02}}
};
const int numtags = sizeof(tag)/sizeof(struct tagInfo);
```

Then, your loop

```
void loop() {
  if (!mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) { return; }
  if (!mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) { return; }
  int i; // declare before the loop because we want to check the value after the loop ends
  for (i = 0; i < numtags; i++) {
    byte len = tag[i].len * 3 + 1;
    if(len == mfrc522.uid.size) { // 4, 7, 10?
      if(!memcmp(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, tag[i].uid, len)) {
        break; // found an exact match so stop the loop
      }
    }
  }
  if (i == NUMTAGS) { return; } // no matches
  // all good here - run the rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Not sure if it's the best way but it works. Thanks for your help.

```
//RFID Password Typer
//If a matching tag is found, the keyboard types
//CTRL-ALT-DEL, then types the password and presses enter
//Which should log you on to a Windows computer
//Or Lock the computer if you're already logged in

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include "Keyboard.h"

#define RST_PIN 9         
#define SS_PIN 10        

byte tag[10]={****,****,****,****,};
byte tag1[10]={****,****,****,***^,};
byte tag2[10]={****,****,****,**^^,};
byte tag3[10]={****,****,****,*^^^,};
char pswd[]="*********\n";      //password, end with just \n
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);  // Create MFRC522 instance

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();              //start SPI
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();       //start RC522 module
  Keyboard.begin();         //start USB keyboard
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);     //LED off
}

void loop() {
  if (!mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) { return; }
  if (!mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) { return; }
  for(byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
    if(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i]!=tag[i]) {
    } else if(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i]!=tag1[i]) {
    } else if(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i]!=tag2[i]) {
    } else if(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i]!=tag3[i]) { return; }
  }
  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA(); //stop tag so we don't get repeats
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH); //LED on so we know we've got tag match
  Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_CTRL);
  Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_ALT);
  Keyboard.press(KEY_DELETE);
  delay(100);
  Keyboard.releaseAll();
  delay(300);
  Keyboard.print(pswd);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW); //LED off
}
```

Comment: no, not the best way at all - look at the logic in testing for a match ... work through it on paper, you'll see it is wrong

Comment: This is **not** the logic you want. You are looping through the UID and looking if **any of the constant tags** have that value in the current place. If you have `tag1 = { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3}` `tag2 = {0x4, 0x5, 0x6}` the tag `{0x4, 0x2, 0x6}` will be accepted although it does not match any tag completely. The other answer is what you'll want.